# Read/Write data in the child of a child Firebase HTML

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Right now, I am able to write to my database like this:

```
var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
firebaseRef.child(codeText).set(messageText);
```

and I can read data like this:

```
var firebaseReadRef = firebase.database().ref().child(child);
firebaseReadRef.on('value', function(datasnapshot){
var data = datasnapshot.val();
}
```

The problem is I can only store data like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKOp1.png and I want to know how to store data like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OSK3.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
firebaseRef.child(codeText).child("Child Name").set(messageText);
```

That way you get another child. You can also specify your reference like this:

```
firebase.database().ref("name/childName").set(messageText);
```

Hope it helped. You might want to check the documentation for more useful information.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write